# Scalaz Task: waiting for a computation that is to be attempted externally

Tags: scala, task, scalaz

I would like to have a function:

```
def waitForTask(body: ⇒ Future[A]): Future[A] = {
    val task = Task{body}
    ???
}
```

such that:

- It would time-out after a duration of `timeOutValue`
- The attempt to run the task would be done externally.

so for instance I would have:

```
queueTask(task: Task[Any]): Unit = tasks += task
```

and then when a condition was satisfied, I would attempt the tasks in the list and somehow return the evaluated value for each task to the client of `waitForTask()` waiting on the task.

therefore, the client:

- would receive the result if the tasks were attempted within say 6 seconds.
- return a TimeOutFailure if the tasks were not attempted within 6 seconds.

I understand that Task has a retry mechanism but I don't want to keep polling, I only want to do it once. Basically, I am asking for a semi-lazy evaluation of the vanilla Future. I don't think I can do it in a very functional way, but I would like to know if it's possible to use the methods provided by `Task` to achieve what I am looking for.

update:

timing out on waitForTask is actually easy once we have the external trigger sorted. Task has a `timed` method and there are other libraries offering similar functionality. so **the problem is essentially waiting for the computation of a task that is not yet attempted**.

Comment: Is it `Future` from `Scalaz` or vanilla Scala? If latter, you might consider just using [Future utils from Monix](https://monix.io/docs/2x/execution/future-utils.html)

Comment: vanila `Future`. I can do a timed evaluation with Monix Future Utils, but what about the external trigger of the task/future?

Comment: Not sure I entirely understand the question, but you might find this library useful https://github.com/Verizon/delorean